# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring. I am stuck in one problem although I have looked this in various sites and followed the question that are here with this topic but still I am not able to find a solution.

I'm getting this error

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ReadingsMVC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

My web.xml is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Spring-Servlet is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.abc.reading.controller"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="/WEB-INF/jsp/.*jsp">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      </bean>
   </beans>
```

My Java Rest Controller code is

```
package com.lucidtechsol.reading.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.abc.reading.exception.InvalidRangeException;
import com.abc.reading.exception.NegativeNumberException;
import com.abc.reading.utilities.RandomNumberGenerator;

@RestController
public class ReadingController {

    @RequestMapping("/reading")
    public String getReading() throws NegativeNumberException, InvalidRangeException {

       return  new Integer(new RandomNumberGenerator().generateRandomNumber(100, -50)).toString();

        }
}
```

My TestRandomNumberGenerator is

```
package com.abc.testcase;



import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.abc.reading.exception.InvalidRangeException;
import com.abc.reading.exception.NegativeNumberException;
import com.abc.reading.utilities.RandomNumberGenerator;

public class TestRandomNumberGenerator {
    int upper;
    int lower;
    RandomNumberGenerator generator;

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        generator = new RandomNumberGenerator();
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        generator = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testPositive() {
        upper = 10;
        lower = 5;
        try {
            assertTrue(upper >= generator.generateRandomNumber(lower, upper));
        } catch (NegativeNumberException | InvalidRangeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test(expected = NegativeNumberException.class)
    public void testNegativeNumberException() throws NegativeNumberException,
            InvalidRangeException {
        upper = 10;
        lower = -5;
        generator.generateRandomNumber(lower, upper);
    }
    @Test(expected = InvalidRangeException.class)
    public void testInvalidRangeException() throws NegativeNumberException,
            InvalidRangeException {
        upper = 30;
        lower = 10;
        generator.generateRandomNumber(lower, upper);
    }
}
```

My exception java file are-

InvalidException

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.abc.reading.exception;

/**
 * @author kuppusamys
 *
 */
public class InvalidRangeException extends Exception {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4348179544370409821L;

    public InvalidRangeException() {
        super();
    }

    public InvalidRangeException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

NegativeException

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.abv.reading.exception;

/**
 * @author kuppusamys
 *
 */
public class NegativeNumberException extends Exception {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7903564384519771246L;

    public NegativeNumberException() {
        super();
    }

    public NegativeNumberException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

RandomNumberGenerator is

```
import java.util.Random;

import com.abc.reading.exception.InvalidRangeException;
import com.abc.reading.exception.NegativeNumberException;

public class RandomNumberGenerator {
    public int generateRandomNumber(int upper, int lower) throws NegativeNumberException, InvalidRangeException {
        if (lower < 0) {
            throw new NegativeNumberException(
                    "Lower bound of range is negative -->" + lower);
        }
        if (upper < 0) {
            throw new NegativeNumberException(
                    "Upper bound of range is negative -->" + upper);
        }
        if (upper < lower) {
            throw new InvalidRangeException("Upper bound of range -->" + upper
                    + " is smaller than lower bound of range -->" + lower);
        }

        return lower + new Random().nextInt(upper - lower);
    }
}
```

My .jsp file is- Hello

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>spring mvc</title>
</head>
<body>
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

I am not understanding what I am doing wrong. Please help me!

if you don't understanding please comment

Answer (score 0):

Try with http://localhost:8080/reading

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

     <bean class="com.abc.reading.controller.ReadingController" />

     <bean id="viewResolver"
                  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
       </property>
       <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
       </property>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I am using this only but it is not working. I also tried http://localhost:8080/ReadingsMVC/ it is also not working

Comment: I am not understanding should I change the web.xml?

Comment: Yes, try changing this part. <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Comment: I changed that part to  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> but still not working...it says description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Change the new code, it works me.

Comment: changed .but same error occur

Comment: Change again. Check this part: <bean class="com.abc.reading.controller.ReadingController" /> I didn't see you have not ReadingController at end.

Comment: that also not working. my random number working but jsp page not showing.

Comment: i solve that problem.